# is it possible to generate a list of seq() for loop in r?

Tags: r, loops, seq

I am very new to R and I have some problem on performing loop using `seq()` and list. I have search on the QnA in SO, yet I have to find the same problem as this. I apologize if there is a duplicate QnA on this.
I know the basic on how to generate sequence of number and generate using list, however I am wondering whether we can generate a list of sequence for each loop.

this is an example of my code

```
J <- seq(50,200,50) # (I actually wanted to use 1: J to generate a sequence of each combinations . i.e: 1:50, 1:100 etc)

K <- seq(10,100,10) #(same as the above)

set.seed(1234)

for (i in J) {

    for (j in K){
        f <- rnorm(i + 1) # the f value I would like it to be generate in terms of list, since the j have 4 sequence value, if possible, could it adhere to that?

    }

}
```

i try using both sequence and list function, but i keep getting either messages:

```
if print(i)
```

output

```
[1]1

.
.
.

[1]50
```

Warning message:

> In 1:(seq(50, 200, 50)) :
>    numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
>
> for (i in 1:list(seq(50,200,50)))
>
> Error in 1:list(seq(50, 200, 50)) : NA/NaN argument

May I know, whether such loop combinations can be perform? Could you please guide me on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, however it comes out with the values from [1]..[300]. I actually wanted it to perform the simulation loop from [1]..[50], then perform for the next loop [1]..[100] which is according to the seq(50,200, 50). Does it mean that I need to do it 1 by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not yet sure of what you are asking but is this what you are looking for? It was difficult to post this as a comment

```
J <- seq(50,200,50)
l1 <- vector(length = length(J), mode = "list")
for (i in seq_along(J)){    # you know of seq_along() right?
  l1[[i]] = rnorm(J[i])
}
```

---

for the second question where you want lists(J) of lists(K) of matrices : Please do note hat `<<-` has never been a good practice, but for now this is what i could come up with!

Note : to understand what is actually happening, go into the `debug` mode : i.e. after defining `func`, also pass `debug(func)` which will then go into step-by-step execution.

```
l1 <- vector(length = length(J), mode = "list")
l2 <- vector(length = length(K), mode = "list")

func <- function(x){
  l1[[x]] <- l2
  func1 <- function(y) {
    l1[[x]][[y]] <<- matrix(rnorm(J[x]*K[y]), 
                          ncol = J[x], 
                          nrow = K[y])
  }
  lapply(seq_along(l1[[x]]),func1)
}

lapply(seq_along(l1), func)
```

Comment: yes, I think that's the solution because I needed it to run 4 times to loop inside the function, and your solution works. I understand about the seq_along, but can you care to explain to me in regards of the the second line code? l1 <- vector(length = length(J), mode = "list") Is it compulsory to write it down to explain the function that we are going to use? Thank you in advance

Comment: @yannia you need to tell the tool that `l1` is a `list` right. you can either do this or just create a null list using `l1=list()`

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I have tested for other formula, and it works.thank you again for your kind assistance

Comment: @yannia glad to help!

Comment: i have another question, how about for another complicated form of a rnorm matrix, i.e. y <- matrix (rnorm(J * K), J, K)  and we want the list to produce K number of list (as it follows the column of the matrix) do we change the code name to into matrix or we just proceed with the same thing? I try to do with this, i.e.  K <- seq(10,100,10)
l2 <- vector(length = length(K), mode = "list")
for (k in seq_along(J)){   
  l2[[k]] = matrix(rnorm(J[k] * K[k]), J[k], K[k]) 
} it fills all but the last 4 list comes out with NULL. Perhaps, you have any suggestion on this? Thank you for kind help.

Comment: @yannia didn't understand? what would you want as output? mind adding it to the original post itself

Comment: I cant seem to edit the question.As I wanted the sequence to generate in terms of list and begins at 1 for each of sequence, I appreciate the solution provided by @joel.wilson for the above problem. However, there is still some parts that I would like to know further. Apparently,
    [1] 50 100 150 200 #sequence of J
   `[1] 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 # sequence of K`
In this case, l2 = matrix(rnorm(J * K), J, K), if by using these
`K <- seq(10,100,10) 
l2 <- vector(length = length(K), mode = "list") for (k in seq_along(J)){ l2[[k]] = matrix(rnorm(J[k] * K[k]), J[k], K[k]) }
'

Comment: I would get a list of output from [[1]] to [[4]] with the matrix combination (J(number of row) and K(number of column)) as (50 -10, 100 -20, 150 - 30 and 200 - 40) while for the list output from [[5]] - [[10]] is NULL. Also, if possible, I would like it to be in the matrix combinations of J and K i.e. (50-10, 50 -20, 50 -30 ... 200 - 10, 200-20..200-100). May I know, whether I need to add an additional command or perhaps I need to change the entire code completely? I appreciate any suggestion regarding this. Thank you so much.

Comment: do you want a sequence that starts from each of `J` and ends at each of `K`? and what is the role of `rnorm` here?

Comment: The rnorm is for simulation of the elements in the matrix, whereas J(row) and K (column). Is it possible to make a list based on the combination of row J and column K for each of the sequence combination (except with itself)? I.e. row 1:50(J) with column 1:10(K) … 1:50(row) with 1:100 (column) then another list again for the next J and K combination,1:100(row) with 1:10(column) … 1:100(row) with 1:100 (column) and so on? So that, at the end of the loop,will produce 10 list of combinations based on the combination of J and K i.e. (1:50-1:10,...,1:200-1:100)? Could you please guide me on this?

Comment: I tried to do something like `X<- structure(list(expand.grid(J,K)))` and it comes out with that row and column combination that I needed. However, there is only 1 list. I also tried out `X<-as.matrix(expand.grid(J,K))` , I am not sure whether I need to expand it further or change it completely so that the matrix will loop according to the combination and in a list format. Perhaps, a loop code need to be included here? In order for it to loop according to the sequence and the combinations?

Comment: @yannia why is it that you can't edit your question! it's so difficult to understand from these comments.

Comment: @yannia so in total actually 4 lists and within each list , 10 matrices? is that you are looking for?

Comment: My apologies for the inconvenience. Previously, I thought that there would be around 40 list based on the combination. But your suggestion on the 4 main list with each of the 10 matrices (based on the combination), looks much smoother.  Do I need to write a new code for that or I just need to alter the code that you have shown previously?

Comment: @yannia you have asked a completely different question here actually! i have edited my answer.. to incorporate what you have asked for. please post a new question if that's not what you are looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @joel.wilson. It took me some time to try to see what is going on, but now,  I have fully understand the solution for my second question. Previously,I did not know that we need to create a `function` to make the list based on the combination as I thought just using loop is enough. Thanks again.